# Kendo Sortable + AngularJS: click event not triggered

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HVtgUydpEVniVAyW2xlF?p=preview) I have a directive that contains a KendoSortable. I would like to know when the user clicks on any of the sortable divs but the click event is not triggered. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
<dir2></dir2>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

app.directive('dir2', function() {

      var directive = {};

      directive.restrict = 'EA';

      directive.template = '<div kendo-sortable="list" id="listid"></div>';

      directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

           scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){

                if (widget === scope.list) {
                    $('#listid').append ( '<div class="item">11111111</div>');  
                    $('#listid').append ( '<div class="item">22222222</div>');
                    $('#listid').append ( '<div class="item">33333333</div>');
                }

         });


         $('.item').on( "click", function( event ){

            alert('clicked');
            console.log(event);

         });

      };

     return directive;
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to check clicks on whatever uses your directive, or on something within your directive?

Comment: I'm trying to capture clicks on divs with class="item" (the divs in the sortable). I need to get the text of the div that was clicked.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not that familiar with jquery inside angular, and I don't know how angular directives respond to having their template changed .  You might consider using an ng-repeat with a predefined ng-click event as your template.

Answer (score 0):

if your item was generated dynamically, then

```
$('.item').on( "click", function( event ){
//yourcode
});
```

won't work, you need to call the DOM then the object you are listening for.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".item", function( event ){
});
```